# Magento2 : Check it is frontend or backend?

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend

I want to check whether it is front or backend.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Read More: [blog.mageprince.com](https://blog.mageprince.com/how-to-check-if-the-current-area-is-frontend-or-backend/)**

**With objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
echo $state->getAreaCode(); //frontend or adminhtml or webapi_rest
```

**With Dependency Injection**

```
protected $_state;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    $this->_state = $state;
}

public function getArea()
{
    return $this->_state->getAreaCode();
}
```

**Note: As per magento2 coding standards don't use object manager instance directly in files**

Comment: +1 @PЯINCƏ As per Magento coding standard, Don't use full class name in construct method. Declare full class using the use statement and declare only class name to construct() method.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Im not agree with you, please see this question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106096/magento-2-use-statement-versus-direct-class-path

Answer (score 13):

People have answered the question already.
I am just making it better.

```
const AREA_CODE = \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML;

private $_state;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    $this->_state = $state;
}

public function isAdmin()
{
    $areaCode = $this->_state->getAreaCode();
    return $areaCode == self::AREA_CODE;
}
```

Comment: hi @dinesh, can we enable maintainance mode only for admin side?

Comment: No, that option is not available.

Answer (score 6):

Use below code

```
$objectmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state =  $objectmanager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
if($state->getAreaCode() == 'frontend')
  //frontend
else
  //backend
```

Edit : In some cases ( for example shipping calculation ) area code returns "webapi_rest", not "frontend" on frontend side.

Comment: So both frontend and backend can produce calls that come in with webapi_rest, yet your code example still assumes that anything that isn't frontend MUST be backend.

Answer (score 2):

Try code below for check if you are in admin area

```
function df_is_admin($store = null) {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $om */
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State $state */
    $state =  $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    return 'adminhtml' === $state->getAreaCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function isAdmin(){
      return ('adminhtml' == $this->_state->getAreaCode());
 }
```