# Magento 2 How to identify order is placed from frontend or rest API?

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, rest-api, place-order, area

How to identify order is placed from frontend or rest API ?

when we are trying to area code from any event after order placed

```
$this->_checkState->getAreaCode()
```

then we are getting always area code is "webapi_rest"

it must be frontend.

If checkout placed order is using REST API then how to identify order placed is from frontend or rest API or any other medium?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241073/magento2-check-it-is-frontend-or-backend

Comment: @MukeshOjha but it is always show area code is "webapi_rest"

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento checkout page uses rest API thatswhy its giving you result like this.

try getting current layout like this

```
    public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
}

public function yourFunctionName()
{
    $handle = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
    ....
}
```

if it returns something like checkout_index_index then the order is from theme else API

let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: ok checking and let you know

Comment: when i use this code i am getting this "__"