# How to check that my observer file was called from admin or frontend in magento 2?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4.3.p1

I am using `sales_order_save_after` in Global scope. I am creating orders from admin programmatically( Order, Invoice and Shipment). Each and every time this event is calling.

I want to check and update the order increment id with the prefix value only from the front end order.

**How can i check the observer calling from front end scope?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject the `Magento\Framework\App\State` class object in your observer's `__construct` method and store the object into the observer class property, so that you can access `getAreaCode()`.

For example:

```
protected $state;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    $this->state = $state;
}

public function getArea()
{
    return $this->state->getAreaCode();
}
```

Refer: [Magento2 : Check it is frontend or backend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241073/magento2-check-it-is-frontend-or-backend)